# datagridview which is in other form can't refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh

I have two Windows Forms (Form1 and Form2).
Form1 includes one button and datagridview. Form1 shows customers list.
Form2 includes 4 textbox. Form2 is my customer informations edit screen.
I have 2 question :

1. When I press button which is in Form1 I want to see datas in
   textboxes.
2. When I change any textbox.Text content and closed Form2 ; datas
   which is in datagridview are not changed.When I restart
       project no problem all rows in datagridview are changed.

Can you offer me a way to solve this ? To open more when I edit the customers list I want to see it in the datagridview immediately. I want it to be refreshed and see the edited data.(by the way  I tried to use `datagridview.Refresh()` and etc. but it doesn't worked)

Comment: re-set the datasource to the gridview

Comment: just do exactly what you did to display the data in the first place again

Comment: @MutuYolbulan can you tell me specifically please.I really dont understand what you mean.yardımcı olursan sevinirim.)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily share data across forms using the [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) component.

Form1:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Form2:

```
textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", form1.bindingSource1, "CustomerName");
```

For more details see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404320.aspx) MSDN link.